# Search key in HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I'm trying to find the fastest way to **find a key** in a `HashMap` and return it.

I tried using `containsKey` but I'm initializing the object before this so the *hashcode* is different and it can't find it.

I used linear search like this:

```
Box b = null;
Box box = new Box(10, 5);
for (Box e : cells.keySet()) {
    if (box.equals(e)) {
        contains = true;
        b = e;
    }
}
```

`Box` is a class that contains `x` and `y` fields. It works fine but I was wondering if there is a faster way to do it.

Comment: then you should override `hashCode()` so that objects with the same values get the same hashcodes.

Comment: If that code works, `containsKey` will also work. **Except** you override `equals` but forget to also override the `hashCode` method. Which, by the way, violates the contract. If you ever implement a custom `equals` you **must** also implement `hashCode` with the same logic.

Comment: Ok that makes much more sense. you are right I didn't override hashCode. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override `hashcode()` and `equals()` if you `Box` class first to be able to deal good with `HashMap`

---

Then you can simply do :

```
Box box = new Box(10, 5);
Box b = cells.containsKey(box) ? box : null;
```

Comment: One more thing to keep in mind: elements that are used as keys, should be immutable - at least the properties used in `equals()` and `hashCode()` should not be changeable (or in short: the hashcode for a key should never change). Mutable keys are a bad thing in maps which can lead to hard to track bugs.